# Html link is not working in Hotmail

Tags: php, email, hotmail

I am using the mail() function in php to send a html mail with this html content:

```
<a href="http://localhost/#/confirm?key=$confirmationLink">
http://localhost/#/confirm?key=$confirmationLink</a>
```

The href outputs like this in hotmail:
http://localhost/#/confirm%3fkey%3df327e518193e515f7c8226a006d0bc5934
and does not work when I click the link.

It works fine in gmail, which outputs href as:
http://localhost/#/confirm?key=ee9b70ca92c47210525743a4e7ab112535

**How to make it work in Hotmail?**

This is how I use the mail() function:

```
$to = 'blbl@blblb.dk';
$from = 'contact@bla.dk';
$subject = 'blabla';
$message = <<<EOD
<html>
<body>      
<pre>
To get started please verify your account by clicking this link: 
<a href="http://localhost/#/confirm?key=$confirmationLink">http://localhost/#/confirm?key=$confirmationLink</a>

</pre>
</body>
</html>
EOD;
$headers = "From: $from\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$mail = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Hotmail encodes the url so you need to decode the url when a user gets back to you site. I think you call an AJAX script (cause of the hash in the url) and send the parameters to the server-side script - if so then use JavaScript's decodeURI function and only then send the url parameters. Anyway the answer is: You need to decode the url.

Comment: The decodeURI did not work, but thanks for leading me on the right path. The javascript command: unescape(url) worked.